# Cucumber: Shared steps, where to place them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Say I have a feature line like this:

```
And I fill in "Category" with "soccer"
```

Even though this particular feature line is associated with a search form, I will need to use the **same kind** of step when dealing with forms in other features.

Where do you guys place this kind of **"shared" steps**, or in other words, steps that will be used in different features/scenarios?

I have created a file called **shared_steps.rb** with this content:

```
And /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |field,value|
  fill_in field, :with => value
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with placing this type of step in a 'shared_steps.rb' file, that seems perfectly fine.

I would, however, recommend trying to use steps with more explanatory language, such as 'And I search for "soccer" equipment'.  There are well documented reasons that [the built-in web_steps.rb file is no longer included with Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/f027440965b96b780e84e50dd47203a2838e8d7d/History.md).

Comment: Yep, nothing wrong with shared steps. You could name them "soccer steps" or whatever seems appropriate for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That step is actually self explanatory in the context of the scenario :)